# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'pProductId ='

Tags: asp.net, image, ms-access, syntax-error

Hi I am trying to retrieve pProductImage that contains ie. ~/Images/pic1.jpg (images url) from products table and use the pProductId as a identifier to display different images according to the Id.

this is my cataglogue.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;


public partial class Catalogue : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ImageId = Request.QueryString["Img"];

        string sqlText = "SELECT pProductImage FROM Products WHERE pProductId = " +ImageId;

        OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnection"].ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, mDB);

        mDB.Open();
        OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr["pProductImage"]);
        }
        mDB.Close();

    }
}
```

and in my cataglogue.aspx (the image to display in the image control)

```
<div>

    <img src="Catalogue.aspx?pProductId=2" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: what is there in the database image or image path?

Comment: the image path of my image

Comment: why are you using `Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr["pProductImage"]);`

Comment: do you want to create a handler type of functionality. where you just pass the id and it should return the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing image url in your database table then you need to treat it as a string data - for example

in code-behind:

```
protected string GetProductImgUrl(int productId)
{
   var sqlText = "SELECT pProductImage FROM Products WHERE pProductId = " + productId.ToString();
   using(var mDB = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnection"].ConnectionString))
   {
       mDB.Open();
       var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, mDB);
       using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
          if (rdr.Read())
          {
            return ResolveUrl((rdr["pProductImage"]).ToString());
          }
       }
   }
   return ResolveUrl("~/images/NotAvailable.png");     // Not available image
}
```

And in mark-up

```
<div>
    <img src='<%= GetProductImgUrl(2) %>' alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: i have another query now that i am able to display the images. when i click the image it will direct me to the productdetail.aspx of the product. How do i achieve this?

Comment: @MalcolmNathanielNg, as per SO guidelines, you should really post another question (you may provide link to this question)! Said that, to navigate to details page, you need to wrap your image into an anchor tag, for example, `<a href="ProductDetails.aspx?id=2"><img src='<%= GetProductImgUrl(2) %>' alt="" /></a>`